# Doctrine 2: Recursively select all self-referenced associated entities (NestedSet)

Tags: tree, doctrine-orm, dql

I have defined a self-referenced entity: **Category** [as shown in the docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-self-referencing).

It basically creates a non-sortable tree.

What DQL query should I perform that will select all of the parent, parent's parent....?

**EDIT:** I currently select all categories, left joining their parents . Then I use an entity method to extract all ancestors without additional queries:

```
public function hereToRoot( $allCategories )
{
    $ancestors = array();
    $leftJoinedParent = $this->getParent();
    //add parents
    while ( !is_null($leftJoinedParent) ) {
        $nextAncestor = $allRoles[$leftJoinedParent->getId()];
        $ancestors[] = $nextAncestor;
        $leftJoinedParent = $nextAncestor->getParent();
    }
    return array_reverse($ancestors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have tree-like entities, it's better to use [corresponding extensions](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-behavioral-extensions#tree). GitHub repo for them is [here](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions).

Comment: That's unnecessary complex for my task :). For now the manual PHP manipulation is rather simple.